# UIView Subclass Set Own Height + Constraints In UIViewController + Storyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, subclass

I have a UIViewController subclass that contains a UITableView, a subclass of UIView called ICYCollapsableInputView, and another UIView subclass called ICYHeaderVIew.

ICYHeaderView is the rounded off looking UIView shown in the screenshots.  It contains a round button - the one with the green "add" (+) button.

ICYCollapsableInputView is a view that will for now have a UITextField and a Save button.  I want to be able to expand and collapse this view from the UIViewController by calling the appropriate functions of the ICYCollapsableInputView.

When the user taps the round button on the ICYHeaderView, Ithe ICYCollapsableInputView is supposed to expand in height, pushing down the UITableView. I have the ICYCollapsableInputView expanding and collapsing, but I can't figure out how to get the UITableView to respond to the changes.  (See Animation)

[image: expand/collapse animation]

I colored the main view in the xib with a RED background and the view I added in it with a BLUE background (see screenshot)

[image]

I can resize the ICYCollapsableInputView (as seen in the code and animation) using its own height constraint, but the UITableView constraint seems to ignore it.

Here is the code from ICYCollapsableInputView:

```
class ICYCollapsableInputView: UIView {

var view: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBInspectable public var collapsedHeight: CGFloat = 150 {
    didSet {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = collapsedHeight
    }
}
@IBInspectable public var expandedHeight: CGFloat = 250 {
    didSet {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = expandedHeight
    }
}

// MARK: - Init

func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ICYCollapsableInputView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(frame:)
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(coder:)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()
}


func xibSetup() {
    view = loadFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.collapsedHeight
    var rect = self.frame
    rect.size.height = self.collapsedHeight
    self.frame = rect
    self.view.frame = rect

}

func revealInputView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        var rect = self.frame
        rect.size.height = self.expandedHeight
        self.frame = rect
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.expandedHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

func closeInputView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.collapsedHeight
        var rect = self.frame
        rect.size.height = self.collapsedHeight
        self.frame = rect
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

}

 }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have The same issue. Does it happen because the view is changing its own height?

Answer (score 0):

All you need ia just changing the height constraints.

```
    func revealInputView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.expandedHeight //or 250
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func closeInputView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.collapsedHeight //or 150        
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

And Constraints in Storyboard should be following

for inputVW

Trailaing space to superview - 0 , leading space to superview - 0, top space to superview - 0 , bottom space to tableview - 0

for TableView

top space to inputVw - 0, leading space to superview - 0, trailing space to super view - 0, bottom space to superview - 0

Comment: I have tried that.  It does the same thing with the exception that the main frame of the ICYCollapsableInputView (the red part) does not change.

Comment: In the image 3 - in the constraints it showing 4 of 4. Where is the height constraint??

Comment: I have the height constraint set on the ICYCollapsableInputView xib.  You can see it in image 2.

Comment: I want to add that I know I can have a height constraint set on the view controller (which works) but I want to encapsulate the ICYCollapsableInputView and have it set its own height depending on what subviews I add to it - if that's even possible.